# Ruby on Rails - Rounding ones, tens and hundred digit places

Tags: ruby

I want to round of the ones and tens digit positon for the value..

if it is 1999, it should display as 1900

and if it is 19999 it should display as 19000

code goes like this

## {overall_cost.to_money.format(:no_cents)}

Comment: for 19999, it should be 19900? why 19000?

Comment: because only 2 significant digits are required?

Answer (score 6):

You can round like this:

```
(n.to_i / 100) * 100
```

However, you are asking for a monkey patch so that :nocents is a valid argument to... money, I guess.  I poked around the rails source and didn't see where the monkey patch should go.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
def myround(value)
  return value if value < 100
  temp = value.to_s
  temp[0..1] + "0" * (temp.lenth - 2)
end
```